# How To Use Awk To Print Between Two Positional Parameters

Tags: awk

Is there a way to print everything after a positional parameters using awk? What I would like the following command to print is "p4 p5 p6 p7"

```
echo p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | awk '{print $4...}'
```

---

Furthermore, is it possible to print between two positional parameters. The following printing "p4 p5 p6"

```
echo p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | awk '{print $4...$6}'
```

I would like to avoid using regex and having to type: awk '{print $4" "$5" "$6}'

Comment: Some ideas [here](http://backreference.org/2014/10/13/range-of-fields-in-awk/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081916/how-to-print-all-the-columns-after-a-particular-number-using-awk). Basically, use `cut` instead!

Comment: Several solutions have been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626274/print-all-but-the-first-three-columns. None of them as short as `cut` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parameters are dependably separated by exactly one space each, you could use `cut` as follows:

```
echo p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | cut -d' ' -f4-   # For p4 onwards
echo p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | cut -d' ' -f4-6  # For p4 to p6
```

If you want whitespace separated parameters the way `awk` parses them, dependably, it gets more complicated.  For an example of what I'm talking about and how the above may not always do what you want, try:

```
printf '%s   ' p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | cut -d' ' -f4-
printf '%s   ' p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | cut -d' ' -f4-6
```

You can see that `cut` is treating *each* space as a delimiter, rather than any sequence of consecutive spaces as a delimiter the way `awk` does.  You can force `awk` to do what you want with a for loop:

```
echo p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | awk '{for (a=4;a<=NF;a++) {printf "%s ", $a} printf "\n"}'
```

However this does leave a trailing space at the end of the line.  This can be addressed, but it gets messier and messier.  Depending on your requirements, the `cut` command may be just fine.

Comment: Thank you. This clarified many questions for me. In your second this can be overcome by piping text through sed with `printf '%s ' p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | sed 's/ \+/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f6-`

Comment: @DerekMaier, yes, that's true, but don't forget to add extra `sed` operations to strip leading and trailing spaces.  Also I would use `[[:space:]]` to catch tabs et. al. instead of just literal space characters: `sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]\+//;s/[[:space:]]\+$//;s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g'` should do it.  I considered including this in my answer, but see above note about "it gets messier and messier."  But yes, this `sed` command piped to `cut` handles all edge cases I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` can't do it (without using a loop of some kind), but `perl` can.

Remember, though, that `perl` arrays are zero-based (while `awk` array indexes start from 1).

For example, using `perl`'s `-a` option for `awk`-like auto-splitting:

```
$ echo p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | perl -lane 'print "@F[3..$#F]";'
p4 p5 p6 p7 

$ echo p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | perl -lane 'print "@F[2,4,6]";'
p3 p5 p7

$ echo p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 | perl -lane 'print "@F[1..3]";'
p2 p3 p4
```

Notes: `-l` turns on perl's automatic handling of line-endings, and `-n` wraps it in a loop that processes the input line-by-line without any automatic output (similar to sed's -n option.  `-p` does the same but automatically prints each input line after it has been examined and/or modified by the rest of the script).   See `man perlrun`.

see `man perldata` or `perldoc perlvar` for more info on arrays and array slices.

Because the array slices are being printed inside a double-quoted string, it uses the value of `$"` aka `$LIST_SEPARATOR` to separate the array elements.  If they were printed/used outside a double-quoted string, there'd be no separator at all between the elements.  See `man perlvar` or `perldoc perlvar` and search for LIST_SEPARATOR.

Finally, use perl's `-F` option if your field delimiter is anything but whitespace (`\s+` in PCRE), or split it yourself. e.g.

```
$ echo "p1:p2:p3:p4:p5:p6:p7" | perl -F: -lane 'print "@F[0..4]";'
p1 p2 p3 p4 p5

$ echo "p1:p2:p3:p4:p5:p6:p7" | perl -lne '@F=split /:/; print "@F[0..4]";'
p1 p2 p3 p4 p5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using awk's split function (per previous answer, it does require a for loop):

Description:

```
 "sub_0"         - variable to contain desired output ($0 substring)

 "beg"           - 1st desired field (references 4th element in "pn_ary" array)
                   (external "$beg" shell variable passed into awk (internal "beg" variable)

 "end"           - # of fields in $0 (split function loads each field in $0 as a "pn_ary[n]" element ("1-n"))

 "split(s,a,sep) - "s": string, "a": array, "sep": seperator (splits "s" per "sep", loads "a")
                   ("split" returns # of elements loaded into "pn_ary" array into "end" variable)

 "FS"            - awk system Field Seperator variable

 "[:graph:]"     - Posix bracket expression for visible ASCII chars in range "[\x21-\x7E]"
```

Syntax:

```
 beg="4"

 echo "p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7" |\

 awk '{sub_0="";end=split($0,pn_ary,FS)
       for (i=beg;i<=end;i++) {sub_0=sub_0""FS""pn_ary[i]}     
       print substr(sub_0,match(sub_0,"[:graph:]"))
      }' beg="$beg"
```

Output:

p4 p5 p6 p7